# 1080x1920 420dpi screen not accessing from sw420dp

Tags: android, dimensions

I am creating different values folder for supporting different screen sizes.The following are the folders:

```
values-sw320dp-hdpi
values-sw320dp-xhdpi
values-sw320dp-xxhdpi

values-sw420dpi
values-sw560dpi

values-sw480dp-hdpi
values-sw480dp-xhdpi
values-sw480dp-xxhdpi

values-sw600dp
values-sw720dp
```

In the list of devices provided by Android Studio there is **1080x1920 420dpi**.It should access dimens values from **values-sw420dp**.But instead it is accessing from **sw320dp-xxhdpi**.The layout in **1080x1920 420dpi **looks slightly different from **1080x1920 xxhdpi**. Can anyone explain to me why it is not accessing from its own folder?Or could you explain to me the correct way to create a layout so that it support different screen sizes with different densities?I have referred different sites.They are confusing..Please help me!!

Comment: @ScottishUser..Any idea??

Comment: It seems to me that you're comparing "by hand" totally different values. 420dp is 420 density dependent pixels, while 420dpi is 420 dependent pixels per inch. While obviously correlated, they cannot be compared using direct measuring.

Comment: Can you tell me correct way of creating multiple values folders for a layout so that is supports all screen sizes??

Comment: i am not sure but check like this instead of swXXX: values-hdpi below <=5 inch,values-mdpi <=4,values-xhdpi<=7inch,values-xxhdpi above 7 inch.

Comment: Have you tried this approach before?Has it worked for you??

Comment: There is a 5 inch phone with xxhdpi

Comment: I do not see this problem as using "the correct way". There is a simple way, that is using `values-<prefix>dpi` folders only, and customizable way which depends of your specific needs. I was trying to point out that you are comparing something uncomparable.

Answer (score 3):

> I am creating different values folder for supporting different screen sizes.

First, using density qualifiers (e.g., `-xhdpi`) on resource types other than `drawable` and `mipmap` is a serious code smell. Almost assuredly, you are not going to get the results that you expect.

Second, there is no `-sw420dpi` or `-sw560dpi` qualifier. You could have `-sw420dp` or `-sw560dp`, to say that you want to use these resources for those screen size thresholds. However, such directories would never be used, because of your density qualifiers on directories like `values-sw320dp-hdpi`.

> In the list of devices provided by Android Studio there is 1080x1920 420dpi.It should access dimens values from values-sw420dp

No, it should not.

The smallest width of that screen is 1080px. 1080px, at 420dpi, is 411dp (1080 * 160 / 420). 411 < 420. Hence, anything that is `-sw420dp` will not qualify.

> But instead it is accessing from sw320dp-xxhdpi.

Partially, that is because 411 is lower than 420.

Partially, that is because you are using density qualifiers here, which short-circuit a lot of the "normal" rules for resource selection.

> The layout in 1080x1920 420dpi **looks slightly different from **1080x1920 xxhdpi.

Your question has no layouts, so nobody can comment on that.

> Can anyone explain to me why it is not accessing from its own folder?

There is no "its own folder".

> Or could you explain to me the correct way to create a layout so that it support different screen sizes with different densities?

- Use `layout` resources based on screen size and (perhaps) orientation (e.g., `res/layout-sw420dp/`)
- Use `dimen` resources measured in `sp` (for sizing text or things that are dominated by text) or `dp` (for everything else) in those layout resources (e.g., `<dimen name="margin">16dp</dimen>`)
- Use density qualifiers, and *maybe* size qualifiers, for `drawable` and `mipmap` resources (e.g., `res/drawable-hdpi/`)

Frequently, that is sufficient.

> I have referred different sites.They are confusing

Perhaps consider reading a book.